# Using cookies to not show a popup based on particular actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

I"m currently using a fancybox to deliver content in a popup 2 seconds after a page loads. I'd like implement something that would remove the annoyance of this popping up every single time a page on the site is loaded.

Ideally, if a visitor clicked the "close" button on the fancybox, the pop-up wouldn't appear for them until the next day. If the visitor clicked the link that's in the popup, then the popup wouldn't appear until a specified later date.

Here's the code I'm currently using for the popup:

```
// fancybox arguments
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'autoSize': false,
        'width': '650', 
        'height': 'auto'
    });


// Launch fancyBox on first element
setTimeout(function(){$(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');},2000)
```

I assume this can be done using js cookie, but i'm not sure how the syntax would work based off what I'm trying to do with two different expirations .

**EDIT:**

Here's the HTML that is used for the pop-up:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <a class="fancybox" href="#donation-info" alt=""/></a>
    <div id="donation-info">
        <?php if (get_field('donation_box_text', 'option')){
            echo '<h2>To all our readers:</h2>';
            echo '<p>' . get_field('donation_box_text', 'option') . '</p>';
            echo '<div style="text-align:center"><a href="' . get_field('donation_link', 'option') . '" id="donate" class="donate-link" />Donate</a></div>';
        }; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried updating the above function to include cookies, from the best of my guesstimation, to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ($.cookie('noShowDonation')) $('.fancybox').hide();
    else {
        $("#donate").click(function() {
            // fancybox arguments
                $(".fancybox")
                    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
                    .fancybox({
                        padding : 0,
                        'autoDimensions': false,
                        'autoSize': false,
                        'width': '650', 
                        'height': 'auto'
                    });

            // Launch fancyBox on first element
                setTimeout(function(){$(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');},2000)
                        $.cookie('noShowDonation', true);    
                    });
                }
            });
```

**EDIT #2 -- Updated code**
Using the code suggested by @Rob below, I tried adding the configurations to the fancybox as well as the timeout, however, no luck. Here's the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30Lxfc6r/

Comment: hi! have you in mind the use of single cookie?

Comment: @misterwolf, I'm not really sure. Maybe a cookie isn't necessary and this can be accomplished with HTML localstorage or something. I'm open to suggestions for the best implementation. Thoughts?

Comment: Seeing as you're already using jQuery, check out the cookie library - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @Rob thanks! I've had a look at that, but i'm not even sure where to start to trigger different expiration dates based on user interaction.

Comment: +1 for DOM storage. Cookies get sent along with every HTTP request: your backend probably doesn't care about this.

Comment: @KyleGilbertson any suggestion on how to implement that for this situation?

Comment: @NWTech have look at [Mozilla's Using the Web Storage API article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). This is an alternative to the cookie. It only stores strings, so store the date you can start showing the fancy box again like `window.localStorage.setItem(cookieName, "" + (Date.now() + (86400000 * 7)));`.  I tried to get this to work in your fiddle, but I can't get the fancybox to show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated my answer with a JSBin example based on the FancyBox docs.
https://jsbin.com/bajocosese/edit?html,console,output
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

```
$(function () {
  // Define cookie name
  var cookieName = 'hide_donate';

  // Configure fancyBox
  $('.fancybox').fancybox({
      autoDimensions: false,
      autoSize: false,
      height: 'auto',
      padding: 0,
      width: 650,
      beforeLoad: function() {
        // Returning false will stop fancybox from opening
        return ! $.cookie(cookieName);
      },
      afterClose: function() {
        // Set cookie to hide fancybox for 1 day
        $.cookie(cookieName, true, { expires: 1 });
      }
  });

  // Handle donate click event
  $('a#donate').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); 

      // Hide fancybox and set cookie to hide fancy box for 7 days
      $.fancybox.close();
      $.cookie(cookieName, true, { expires: 7 });
  });

  // Launch fancyBox on first element
  setTimeout(function () {
      $(".fancybox").trigger('click');
  }, 2000);
});
```

**Remember, this example will only work once, unless you delete the cookie, or change the cookie name.**

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I gave this a go with no luck. I think it's due to my original code including the timeout: `setTimeout(function(){$(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');},2000)` ...Anyways, I've updated the original post to include your suggested code.

Comment: @NWTech, I have updated my answer above with an example this time. All appears to be working.